# Looking for single digits in my string in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, string-search

I want to search my string for single digits, for every different single digit in python. If it contains 1 in want to add 1 to another list and same for other digits.

```
  //single-digit found
 ar.append(single-digit)
```

example-string: `ap126ks8`

```
 ar=[1,2,6,8]
```

Comment: at least try to solve the problem before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
strr="ap126ks8"
ar=[]
for i in strr:
    if i.isdigit():
        ar.append(i)
```

Or using list comprehension

```
strr="ap126ks8"
ar=[i  for i in strr if i.isdigit()]
```

output

> ['1', '2', '6', '8']

Answer (score 0):

A Simpler Way Is To Create A List.

```
example-string = "ap126ks8ar"
ar = []
numbers = "0123456789"

i=0
while i< len(example-string):
    if example-string[i] in numbers :
         ar.append[example-string[i]
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions to solve this easily. Try the following:

```py
import re
example_str = 'ap126ks8'
ar = re.findall('[0-9]', example_str)
print(f"The returned list of numbers found in the string is {ar}.")
```

The output:
`The returned list of numbers found in the string is ['1', '2', '6', '8'].`

**EDIT:** If you want your resulting list to be integers, you can define an empty list and loop through the returned `ar` list, converting each item to integer and appending to the empty list as shown here:

```py
int_list = []
for i in ar:
  i = int(i)
  int_list.append(i)
print(f"The resulting list of integers is {int_list}.")
```

Output: `The resulting list of integers is [1, 2, 6, 8].`